# PipelineException: No mask_token ([MASK]) found on the input

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I am getting this error "PipelineException: No mask_token ([MASK]) found on the input"
when I run this line.
fill_mask("Auto Car .")

I am running it on Colab.
My Code:

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForMaskedLM
from pathlib import Path
from tokenizers import ByteLevelBPETokenizer
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForMaskedLM


paths = [str(x) for x in Path(".").glob("**/*.txt")]
print(paths)

bert_tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

from transformers import BertModel, BertConfig

configuration = BertConfig()
model = BertModel(configuration)
configuration = model.config
print(configuration)

model = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

from transformers import LineByLineTextDataset
dataset = LineByLineTextDataset(
    tokenizer=bert_tokenizer,
    file_path="./kant.txt",
    block_size=128,
)

from transformers import DataCollatorForLanguageModeling
data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(
    tokenizer=bert_tokenizer, mlm=True, mlm_probability=0.15
)

from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./KantaiBERT",
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
    num_train_epochs=1,
    per_device_train_batch_size=64,
    save_steps=10_000,
    save_total_limit=2,
    )

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    train_dataset=dataset,
)

trainer.train()

from transformers import pipeline

fill_mask = pipeline(
    "fill-mask",
    model=model,
    tokenizer=bert_tokenizer,
    device=0,
)

fill_mask("Auto Car <mask>.").     # This line is giving me the error...
```

The last line is giving me the error mentioned above. Please let me know what I am doing wrong or what I have to do in order to remove this error.

Complete error: "f"No mask_token ({self.tokenizer.mask_token}) found on the input","

Comment: Oh.. I have found out the issue. I was passing <mask> instead of [MASK]. that is why it was giving me the error. Thanks to @cronoik again for helping me to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if you have already found the error, a recommendation to avoid it in the future. Instead of calling

```py
fill_mask("Auto Car <mask>.")
```

you can do the following to be more flexible when you use different models:

```py
MASK_TOKEN = tokenizer.mask_token

fill_mask("Auto Car {}.".format(MASK_TOKEN))
```

Comment: Thanks. You are the best. :)

Comment: Hi cronoik. Hope you are doing fine. I am facing another issue. Can you please take a look at this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67580591/after-updating-the-tokenizer-linebylinetextdataset-keep-on-loading-forever

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but in my case this solution doesn't work. Very strange. Printing `print("mask token: {}".format(tokenizer.mask_token))` clearly indicates that it's expecting "[MASK]", but it still complains that there's no mask token. Any thoughts where else I might look? I've also verified that `mask_token_id` is the expected token.

Comment: @jbm Please open your own question and include all the details. I will have a look.

Comment: Thanks, @cronoik. Digging in a little further I've discovered that there's some confusion in loading the tokenizer's vocab.txt in my notebook... haven't figured out how it's happening yet, but it's tokenizing "[MASK]" as 3 UNKs (presumably for "[" "MASK", and "]").

Comment: Sounds like the special tokens are not set properly. Can you call `tokenizer.special_tokens_map`? @jbm

Answer (score 3):

If the model implementation changes the token to be identified (some identify , some [mask]), then you get into trouble. It is better to use f strings and pass the argument. The advantage of using an f-string is that it is intuitive to understand.

The following code works for me -

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

mask_fill = pipeline("fill-mask", model="bert-base-uncased")
mask_fill(f"The gaming laptop is {tokenizer.mask_token} and I have loved playing games on it.", top_k=2)
```